# Specify attribute in XSD for XMLIgnoreAttribute

Tags: c#, xsd

How to specify an attribute in XSD so that when C# classes are generated using XSD tool that particular attribute is generated as property with XMLIgnore attribute?

How to tweak XSD or generation of C# code to get something like this,

```
[Serializable]
public class Person {

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string NickName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, `XmlIgnore` is for things that **aren't related** to the xsd, so xsd is *never* going to generate a member that it doesn't know about. If you have a requirement to add non-xml-related members to the xsd-generated type, that is where a `partial class` comes in, i.e. in a separate code file (specifying the name c# namespace):

```
// additional (non-xsd) members for Person
partial class Person {
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string NickName {get;set;}
}
```

note that the **other** .cs file (from the xsd) has the `.Name` etc

Comment: Thanks! Marc. I did it with partial class. I read some details about parameters file using XSD tool couldn't understand the scope of it. I though maybe it was possible using that.

Comment: Strange I didn't knew I have to wait sometime before accepting your answer. 3 more minutes :)